# Suggestions or techniques for modeling / texturing large pile of towels

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[Update]
Just wanted to post my solution on this. I ended up stitching together a repeating texture map of towels in photoshop that I applied to a displaced and sculpted sphere. Not the greatest but should be passable.

I added some cloth sim towels around the front edge for realism.

[image]

[Original]
I will also have a character grabbing smaller bunches of towels for bagging. I have worked with cloth simulations, but it seems like overkill and inefficient to build the pile towel by towel. Thank you for any help!

Richard

[image: Pile of towels]